# C++ Removing elements of 2D vector using std::remove_if

Tags: c++, c++11

I've got a 2D vector containing data and I need to remove the elements/blocks if they do not warrant consideration (based on a predicate function). Here is the function:

```
bool thresholdNegative (vector<double> val)
{

//short threshold = 10000;
double meansquare = sqrt ( ( std::inner_product( val.begin(), val.end(), val.begin(), 0 ))/(double)val.size() );

if(meansquare < 0)
{
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
 }
```

And I use the following:

```
std::remove_if(std::begin(d), std::end(d), thresholdNegative);
```

Where `d` is the 2D vector containing all of the data.

The problem is that: It doesn't seem to remove any of the information from the block, even though, the function `thresholdNegative` does return true.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you *read* what `remove_if` does?

Comment: I just can't stand seing possible large objects being passed by value. Please make this `bool thresholdNegative (vector<double> val)` into this `bool thresholdNegative (vector<double> const& val)`

Comment: Perhaps my math is broken, but how can this function ever return true?  How can `meansquare` ever be negative, unless that is some non-standard version of `sqrt`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley What do you mean the method is wrong?

Comment: @user1326876: `sqrt` (the one from the standard) returns the principal (positive) square root for positive numbers, and `NAN` for negative numbers.  So `meansquare` can never be less than 0.  So your function can never return `true`.

Comment: Besides the fact that `meansquare` cannot be negative, you can simply return an expression that evaluates to `bool`. You don't need the messy `if-else`: `return meansquare < 0; // maths joke`

Answer (score 5):

That's how `remove_if` works. It doesn't actualy remove anything from the container (how could it, it only gets two iterators?), instead it just reorders the elements so those that are supposed to stay in the container are gathered at the beginning of the container. The function then returns an iterator to the new end of the container that you can use to actualy remove elements.

```
d.erase( std::remove_if(begin(d), end(d), threshold_negative), end(d) );
```

The above line uses what's called [Erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

Comment: @jrok So it would therefor be.. `for(i = std::begin(d); (i < std::end(d); i++)` in order to remove the elements?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You're right, I changed the wording. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @jrok But, if I do this and still do: `std::cout << d.size();` it is exactly the same?

Comment: @user1326876 Then maybe your predicate doesn't work correctly (I haven't checked it).

Answer (score 2):

Erasing is done by:

```
auto newEnd = std::remove_if(std::begin(d), std::end(d), thresholdNegative);
d.erase(newEnd, end(d));
```

I highly suggest you [read some documentation for std::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)